Sequence Number increase in TCP
I am having some confusion on when the sequence number increases.

Basically, I understand that the sequence number increases for the 3-way handshake due to the SYN flag being set. However, why does the sequence number increase for B's second response?
Shouldn't it have stayed the same due to no new flags being set as well as no data being set?

The sequence number describes the start of the data in the current packet. The ack number describes the end of the received data. Thus if the first SYN packet from B (packet 2 in the diagram) has a seq of 3456 then the next packet from B (packet 4 in the diagram) must use a seq of 3457, which also matches the ack from A in the previous packet.  The strange thing in your image is instead the ack of 2485 in packet 4, which could only happen if packet 3 contains data (which is not shown though).
